# Jquery или JavaScript в Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

Я использую angular route, и использовал YouTube video API и написал этот код в шаблоне(в файле .html).Когда я загружаю страницу всё нормально работает, а когда перехожу между страницами(без обновления страницы), то этот код просто не грузится и не работает.
Была ли у кого-то такая проблема и как вы ее решили?)

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      videoId: '_fGbnVXMnHw',
      playerVars: { 'modestbranding': 1, 'showinfo': 0, 'iv_load_policy': 3, 'loop': 1, 'rel': 0 },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      stopVideo();
      done = true;
    }
    else if ( event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING ) {
        $("#play-video").hide();
        $("#player").removeClass("op_op");
    }
    else if ( event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED ) {
    }
  }

  var videos_btn  = $("#play-video");

    videos_btn.on("click", function(){

        $("#player").removeClass("op_op");

        videos_btn.off("click");
    });


  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
  $("#play-video").click( function() {
    player.playVideo();
  })
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») **должны включать** желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Что за код вы добавили? Где он расположен? Как связан с ангуляром?

Comment: Он расположен в .html документе который является тэмплейтом страницы.И вот именно этот код не выполняется.

Comment: Да, яваскрипт код находящийся в html загружаемом по ajax не выполняется. выносите его оттуда

Comment: Но куда его пихать то?В контроллере не работает вообще.

Comment: по этому и нужен _минимальный пример_ - чтобы было видно что вы пробуете и как, и что именно не работает.

Comment: Как мне показать это всё?)

Comment: например сделать пример на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) и сюда вставить ссылку. Естественно не нужно все приложение с 1000 строк и т.д. Пример должен быть минимальным, но чтобы при этом проблема воспроизводилась

Comment: Просто я вот сейчас не смогу это залить(т.к. занят чутка).Я бы залил и дал бы вам знать)

Comment: если в сообщении присутствует `@` и ник, например @Paedus то участнику приходит оповещение. Так что просто напишите тут когда выложите